# post data like this value[0]value hot to get it in php?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am using Ajax and this is my post data:

> auto[0].aantal:1
>   auto[0].berijder:erwrw
>   auto[0].klant:ertert
>   auto[0].ordernummer:345345
>   auto[1].aantal:1
>   auto[1].berijder:werwer
>   auto[1].klant:ertert
>   auto[1].ordernummer:345345
>   auto[2].aantal:1
>   auto[2].berijder:werwer
>   auto[2].klant:ertert
>   auto[2].ordernummer:345345

and in PHP I am doing the following

> ```
> $array = $_POST['auto'];
> for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++) {
> $key=key($array);
> $val=$array[$key];
> if ($val<> ' ') {
>    $message_body .= "<p>" . $key ." = ".  $val ." <p><br> ";
>    }
>  next($array);
> }
> ```

but that is not giving me all the data, what am I doing wrong? and what can I do to get all the data? thanks for the help so far!!

Comment: Your code to post the data is missing

Comment: this is part of my code: name="auto[0].berijder" So I am generating indexes in javascript